# Workrave preferences not showing

Tags: crash

I installed [Workrave](https://github.com/rcaelers/workrave) but when I click preferences they're not showing and the program crashes instead.

[image]

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used Process Monitor and found out Workrave searches for `%appdata%\Workrave\workrave.ini` but this file doesn't exist.

I created an empty file and Preferences works now.